# Every group of order 399 is abelian and not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ a group with order $399$ = ${3*7*19}$, from Sylow-theorem, I know $n_{3}$ must be $1$ or $7$ or $19$ or $133$, for $n_{7}$ must be $1$ or $57$ and for $n_{19}$ must be 1.
I know $n_{19}$ is $1$ for every cases, then $G$ is not simple, but I try to study if $G$ is abelian with a derivate subgroup and I can't do this.

How can I study if $G$ is abelian?

Comment: It is not true that every group of order $399$ is abelian. There is a nonabelian group of order $21$.

Comment: "How can I study if $G$ is abelian?" - have a look at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217485/proving-that-a-group-of-order-pqr-with-conditions-on-those-primes-is-abelian). Also, the group cannot be simple, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242798/given-3-distinct-primes-p-q-r-then-g-pqr-implies-g-not-simple?rq=1).

Comment: Ohh, i try to find a nonabelian group of order $399$, consider case $n_{19}$ = $1$, $n_{7}$ =$1$ and $n_{3}$ = $7$. let $H$  a Sylow $19$- subgroup and $K$ a Sylow 7 -subgroup, then $HK$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $M$ a Sylow 3-subgroup, then i try to do semidirect product of $HK$ and $M$, but is hard.

Comment: You get a nonabelian group as the direct product of a nonabelian group of order $21$ with a cyclic group of order $19$.

Comment: I ask if $G$ is abelian. In the otherwise , i try to find a nonabelian group with a semidirect product. :)

Comment: Ohhhh yeah, i have to study  direct product of order 21. Thank you

Comment: No, you need a semidirect product of order $21$, and then a direct product.